# Was pod racing banned by the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-phantom-menace

Was pod racing banned by the Empire?

We don't see it in the Original Trilogy, although we do see pod racing flags at Maz's castle.

Comment: Note that the [podracing flags were removed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126775/were-the-flags-outside-mazs-temple-changed-for-a-reason)

Comment: Related (not a dupe): https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184335/did-luke-ever-try-podracing

Comment: Speeder racing was during the Empire.  Also it was part of 1980s extended canon and pod racing was was a bit of a homage to the Driods cartoon as i recall, but lack who specifically reused Boonta. 
 https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boonta_Speeder_Race

Answer (score 4):

It was legal during the time of the Empire, then made illegal when the Empire fell and the New Republic took over.

> Vi perked up. “Is there podracing here?” **The dangerous sport had been declared illegal**, but Batuu didn’t seem like the kind of place that lived under the New Republic’s laws.
>
> <sub><sup>[Galaxy's Edge: Black Spire](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy%27s_Edge:_Black_Spire)</sup></sub>

That being said, it's possibly still legal in areas of the Galaxy still held by the rump Empire (mentioned in [*Star Wars: Uprising*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Uprising) as [taking place](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7sQbvXiFAa8bWJrZXNMU3JJZWM/view) in the Anoat Sector, shortly after the death of the Emperor) and areas of the Galaxy under Hutt control, such as Tatooine.